# Could a state legislature select Electoral College electors instead of using a statewide election?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, voting

Instead of using a statewide election to determine its electors for the [Electoral College](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_College_(United_States)), could a state legislature select the electors itself?

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

*[Bush v. Gore](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supct/html/00-949.ZPC.html)*, 531 U.S. 98 (2000) reiterated that the state "*may, if it so chooses, select the electors itself*", and that even though every state currently uses elections to select the electors, the State "*can take back the power to appoint electors*".